# JS HELP to understand Reduce((countsMap, item) => countsMap.set(item, countsMap.get(item) + 1 || 1), new Map))

Tags: javascript, dictionary, counter, reduce

I had a task and I found a perfect solution, though i don't really understand how that works. Can anyone help me to explain that in details? Especially this one `(countsMap, item) => countsMap.set(item, countsMap.get(item) + 1 || 1)`

```
 var testArray = ["dog", "dog", "cat", "buffalo", "wolf", "cat", "tiger", "cat"];
    function compressArray(original) {
        return array.reduce((countsMap, item) => countsMap.set(item, countsMap.get(item) + 1 || 1), new Map());
    }


console.log(compressArray(testArray));
```

Comment: `const res = new Map; for(const el of original) res.set(el, (res.get(el) || 0) + 1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets break it down into the constituent parts

```
const foo = countsMap.get(item); // get the value of key `item` from a Map
const bar = foo + 1 || 1; // Increment foo by 1, or start at 1
// n.b. this works because `undefined + 1; // NaN`, I would instead
// recommend `(foo || 0) + 1`
const baz = countsMap.set(item, bar); // set the value of key `item` to `bar`
// n.b. this is chainable (i.e. returns `countsMap`)
const fn = (x, y) => x + y; // a function which takes x and y, and returns their sum

// so finally,
const reducor = (countsMap, item) => countsMap.set(item, countsMap.get(item) + 1 || 1);
// 1. look up from map
// 2. increment 1, or start at 1
// 3. set back to map
// 4. return map
```

---

#### Array.prototype.reduce

I find the easiest way to express this to someone is to write it longhand

```
const arr = [1, 2, 3]; // some array
const sum = (accumilator, nextValue) => accumilator + nextValue; // some function
// n.b. the return value is the next accumilator
const initialValue = 0;
const result = arr.reduce(sum, initialValue); // 6, i.e. 1 + 2 + 3
```

So what does this look like longhand, e.g. in a for loop?

```
// lets start the same as before
const arr = [1, 2, 3];
const sum = (accumilator, nextValue) => accumilator + nextValue;

// now to calculate the result,
let accumilator = 0; // = initial value
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
    const nextValue = arr[i];
    accumilator = sum(accumilator, nextValue);
}
accumilator; // 6
```

Answer (score 0):

The reduce() method applies a function against an accumulator and each element in the array (from left to right) to reduce it to a single value.

```js
const array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
const reducer = (accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue;

// 1 + 2 + 3 + 4
console.log(array1.reduce(reducer));
// expected output: 10

// 5 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 4
console.log(array1.reduce(reducer, 5));
// expected output: 15
```

For the `=>` called **Arrow functions**, it's works like

```
(param1, param2, …, paramN) => { statements }
```

```js
var materials = ['Hydrogen', 'Helium', 'Lithium', 'Beryllium'];


console.log(materials.map((material) => {
  return material.length;
})); // [8, 6, 7, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

- You use a loop (but fancy - reduce) over an array testArray.
- While doing a loop you use an object (but fancy - Map) to reflect how many times values are noticed in array.
- You use also arrow function, that's why syntax is concise and you don't need to write return statement.